# How to declare property on object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting this error in Xcode:

> Property 'fb_screenshot' not found on object of type 'XCUIDevice'"

How should I declare it?

Here's part of my code:

```
+ (id<FBResponsePayload>)handleGetScreenshot:(FBRouteRequest *)request
{
    [UtilsLogger logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Handling : %@", request.URL.absoluteURL] sender:METHOD_NAME];
    @try {
        NSString *screenshot = [[XCUIDevice sharedDevice].fb_screenshot base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        return [Response withSucessString:screenshot methodName:METHOD_NAME logString:false] ;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return [Response withException:exception methodName:METHOD_NAME];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect a class to have a property it doesn't have? What would this property mean if it existed? What is your code actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `fb_screenshot` from an old version of WebDriverAgentLib. The method was changed to `fb_screenshotWithError:` on 2017-11-01, according to this commit:

https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/commit/79db77ed67ab04127b93e2d64f7a5837e3026227

So, either you're not importing your (old) copy of `WebDriverAgentLib/Categories/XCUIDevice+FBHelpers.h`, or you have a newer version and you are calling a removed method instead of the replacement method.

Comment: That was it. Thank you